# Arduino Wire.onReceive(handler)

Tags: i2c

It says in the description of the function:

> Registers a function to be called when a slave device receives a transmission from a master.

So when does it exactly called? I guess it's not been called for each byte, but its the meaning of receiving transmission from the master. Does it called for each byte? When the master use transmissionBegin? transmissionEnd?

Comment: The functions are `beginTransmission` and `endTransmission`, not what you had.

Answer (score 1):

It is called at the end of the reception of the entire packet - i.e., when the slave receives the final `STOP` bit.  It is passed the number of bytes received (which is the number of bytes you requested since I2C has no way of being able to work out if it is actually receiving real data - see [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10896&reply=10#reply10)) as the only parameter so you know how many bytes you can then read from the internal buffer without overflowing it.

Comment: Yes, so **after** `endTransmission` it would be called - once all of the bytes in the buffer have been transferred, or the transfer failed.

Comment: `It is passed the number of bytes received` - on the AVR versions of the library at least, you get the *number of bytes you asked for* or *zero*. I have a discussion about this [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10896&reply=10#reply10).

Comment: It looks like they fixed it on SAM... I guess the AVR's I2C module isn't as capable as the SAM one and can't work out if it failed to receive or not.

Comment: I don't know how they did that, because the slave doesn't control the clock and can't therefore raise a stop condition. The master is clocking out clock pulses, and reading the results. If the slave stops sending the master just receives 1-bits because of the pull-up resistor.

Comment: I guess it may never receive an ACK from the slave though after the last byte has been sent by it - so it would time out.

Comment: No, it can't be that - when reading the master ACKs the slave, not the slave the master.

Comment: I'm not so hot on I2C, preferring the higher speed of SPI. I have, however, found this very very nice PDF that explains it all in detail: http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf

Comment: From that document: *START and STOP conditions are always generated by the master. (P9).* - I might set up a test and see if the SAM boards actually handle that, or if they simply didn't test it.

Comment: Figure 12 (P15) is pretty much the clincher... there's no way for the master to know if the slave has stopped sending. It just receives "stuff" and blindly fires an ACK back at the slave until it has read its entire quota - when it then sends the stop. I don't see, from that, how they can have actually "fixed" it in the SAM chips.